# Google sheets filtering large data set

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

=FILTER('New List'!A2:BA871, NOT('Old List'!A:BA))

The Goal:

I have 3 sheets
-Sheet 1: The New list of data I need
-Sheet 2: The Old list of data I DONT need
-Sheet 3: The place where the extraction will take place (Where I am inserting the formula)

The Problem: Some of the items from Sheet 2 (the old list), are in sheet 1 (the new list). I need to extract and remove the overlapping data that can be found in both sheets and put that data in the third sheet

Comment: It is unclear how you define data that is "overlapping". It is also unclear how you would like to "remove the overlapping data". Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1):

To show rows that appear in new list and also in old list, use `filter(match())` to identify duplicates by a unique ID column — assuming column `A` here:

`=filter('New List'!A2:BA, match('New List'!A2:A, 'Old List'!A2:A, 0))`

To show rows that appear in new list but not in old list, use `isna(match())` to identify missing entries by a unique ID column:

`=filter('New List'!A2:BA, isna(match('New List'!A2:A, 'Old List'!A2:A, 0)))`

To show rows that appear in old list but not in new list:

`=filter('Old List'!A2:BA, isna(match('Old List'!A2:A, 'New List'!A2:A, 0)))`

To merge the data and show all rows, removing duplicate rows, use `unique()`:

`=unique( { 'New List'!A2:BA; 'Old List'!A2:BA } )`